# Sharepoint 2013 Excel Services not rendering Power View reports inside a workbook

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot, powerview

We want to be able to publish Excel 2013 workbooks containing Power View reports into SharePoint 2013 and see them via Excel Services application.
Currently instead of the actual report we see the default Power View error page without any error message or log entry.

Here is some additional information:
1. The rest of the workbook (regular excel and powerpivot sheets) is rendered correctly.
2. Power View reports created inside SharePoint document libraries (RDLX reports) are rendered correctly.
3. PowerPivot and Power View are reconfigured and veryfied according to official step-by-step guides.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what we might miss or done wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I did a lot of debugging and could finally find a related error message. It's a `NullReferenceException` in `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.SnapshotHandler.RegisterGlobalExtensionHandlers()` method. This exception is thrown only once after application pool reset and when I upload an XLSX workbook to a document library.
I checked the method code in .NET Reflector and seems I've found the section where the exception is being thrown.

```
CustomCaptureSection customCaptureSection = (CustomCaptureSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ReportGalleryCustomCapture");
SnapshotHandler.MaxSnapshotsCount = customCaptureSection.MaxSnapshotsCount;
SnapshotHandler.SnapshotCaptureTimeoutS = (long)((int)customCaptureSection.SnapshotCaptureTimeoutSeconds);
SnapshotHandler.CreateProcessMethodForSnapshot = customCaptureSection.CreateProcessMethodForSnapshot;
```

In my understanding, runtime is not able to get that section from configuration. I tried to find the section name in SharePoint hive and `inetpub` but with no luck. Is there another place I can look for configuration files? Or can someone verify that this section exists at all?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the workbook is stores on premise, your host config is in Office Web Apps Server view mode (SharePoint Server configured to render workbooks by using Office Web Apps Server), and your workbook is opened in the Excel Web App power view sheets are not visible. Is this the mode you're in? They're also not visible on Skydrive.

Comment: No, that's not my case. SharePoint is configured to use Excel Services, so there should be no problem with rendering Power View reports.

Comment: Check out the table halfway down: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-view-in-excel-in-sharepoint-server-or-sharepoint-online-in-office-365-HA103276078.aspx

Comment: Yes, it says On Premise + Excel Services should render interactive Power View reports.

Comment: I will try to replicate it on our systems and get back to you. I forgot to ask is the Powerview add-in and PowerPivot enabled in the excel app creating/viewing the file?

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem did you ever get this solved? Is the Powerview add-in and PowerPivot enabled in the excel app creating/viewing the file?

Comment: I could fix the problem by reinstalling the whole environment several times. I think the issue was in the order of SharePoint and PowerPivot installations. The last time I installed PowerPivot first and created the SharePoint farm through the PowerPivot configuration wizard. Then I installed RS Addin and everything worked. I'll do more experiments and post final results, cause this order of installations does not suit me.

Comment: That is odd, I would make a comment to the MSFT team: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/category/officedev Sorry I couldn't help more. Good luck!